# Seria possível ler o atributo lastModified de um arquivo hospedado no servidor?

Tags: javascript, html5

Com o código a seguir eu consigo ler (e mostrar na console) o conteúdo de um arquivo (myfile.txt) que se encontra hospedado on-line na mesma pasta do mesmo servidor onde esta a página html com o código em questão.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

async function doIt()
{
  let response = await fetch("myfile.txt", {cache: "no-store"});
  let contents = await response.text();
  console.log(contents);
}
    doIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Porem em lugar de ler o conteúdo do arquivo eu preciso ler somente a data/hora da ultima modificação do referido arquivo. Considerando que eu consigo ler o conteúdo do arquivo em questão imagino que também seria possível ler somente os atributos do tal arquivo mas até agora não encontrei a forma de atingir tal objetivo (cabe mencionar que sou bem inexperiente com JavaScript).

Agradeço qualquer ajuda com o tema.

Answer (score -3):

Sugiro experimentar o exemplo abaixo:

```
fetch("/caminho/para/myfile.txt").then(response => response.blob()).then(blob => {
  const file = new File([blob], blob.name);
  console.log(file.lastModifiedDate, file.lastModified);
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Erikf, muito obrigado pela sua sugestão. Experimentei conforme seu exemplo mas ele retorna sempre a data/hora atual e não  a data/hora da ultima modificação do arquivo. Onde será que estou errando?

Answer (score -3):

Eu tinha postado a mesma pergunta no Stackoverflow em ingles e um usuario me respondeu com a solução:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

async function doIt()
{

  var lastMod = null;
  await fetch("myfile.txt", {cache: "no-store"}).then(r => {
    lastMod = r.headers.get('Last-Modified');
    console.log(lastMod);
})
}
    doIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```